# Два поля в одной форме берут имя из одной модели

Tags: ember.js

Имею приложение ember.js:

В модели person имеется поле name. Далее customer имеет внешний ключ на person.name, а executor имеет многие-ко-многим к person.name через member. Когда я делаю выборку query для customer, то загружаю данные модели person (бакэнд выдает не более 10 записей) и в результате для executor тех данных которые изначально были через member.person уже нет.
Как отобразить person.name и для customer и для executor?

model.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  customer: DS.belongsTo('person'),
  executors: DS.hasMany('member'),
});
```

template.hbs

```
<form>
  <p>
    Customer: 
    {{input type="text" value=personValue key-up=(action 'handleFilterCustomer') placeholder="customers"}}
    <ul>
      {{#each model.customers as |customer|}}
        <li>{{customer.name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </p>
  <p>
    Member:
    <select>
      {{#each model.members as |member|}}
        <option value={{member.id}}>{{member.id}} {{member.person.name}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>    
  </p>
</form>
```

route.js

```
model() {
  let currentProject = this.get('session.data.project.id');
  return RSVP.hash({
    customers: this.store.peekAll('person'),
    members: this.store.query('member', {project: currentProject}),
  });
},
```

controller.js

```
personValue: '',
actions: {
  handleFilterCustomer(){
    let filterInputValue = this.get('personValue');

    this.store.unloadAll('person');
    this.get('store').query('person', { name: filterInputValue });
  },
}
```